Must one close session if isolation_level=AUTOCOMMIT?
In configuration below with isolation_level equal to AUTOCOMMIT what will happen to session if we don't close it? Is it safe? I mean connections leaks.
import asyncio

from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession

engine = create_async_engine("postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres", isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")


async def main():
    session = AsyncSession(engine)
    print(await session.execute(text("SELECT 1")))
    # what happen to session if we don't close it? will GC delete it?


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

P.S. I did real queries and got this:
Exception terminating connection <AdaptedConnection <asyncpg.connection.Connection object at 0x106c6da90>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/песочница-zMN9kpQl-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 374, in _close_connection
    self._dialect.do_terminate(connection)
  File "/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/песочница-zMN9kpQl-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 1117, in do_terminate
    dbapi_connection.terminate()
  File "/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/песочница-zMN9kpQl-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 910, in terminate
    self._connection.terminate()
  File "/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/песочница-zMN9kpQl-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1515, in terminate
    self._abort()
  File "/Users/albertaleksandrov/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/песочница-zMN9kpQl-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1567, in _abort
    self._protocol.abort()
  File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 608, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.BaseProtocol.abort
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 836, in abort
    self._force_close(None)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 906, in _force_close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, exc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 795, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
The garbage collector is trying to clean up non-checked-in connection <AdaptedConnection <asyncpg.connection.Connection object at 0x106c6da90>>, which will be terminated.  Please ensure that SQLAlchemy pooled connections are returned to the pool explicitly, either by calling ``close()`` or by using appropriate context managers to manage their lifecycle.
sys:1: SAWarning: The garbage collector is trying to clean up non-checked-in connection <AdaptedConnection <asyncpg.connection.Connection object at 0x106c6da90>>, which will be terminated.  Please ensure that SQLAlchemy pooled connections are returned to the pool explicitly, either by calling ``close()`` or by using appropriate context managers to manage their lifecycle.


I'm not sure what you mean by safe here?  Does it close the connection?  Or is it safe to not use transactions?

This script connects and then makes a session and calls a some test SQL.  The connection is not returned right away on my test setup because the gc doesn't run right away so the connection is dangling until I call gc.collect(). You can see in the output.  Seems for that reason only you would want to close the session to return the connection so it be re-used as soon as possible.  Especially if you were running something that had many parallel threads/tasks running.  Even if it is closed "eventually" this might lead to a pile up of non-returned connections and overflow your pool.
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pprint import pprint

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from time import sleep


def get_engine(env):
    PG_URI = f"postgresql+psycopg://{env['DB_USER']}:{env['DB_PASSWORD']}@{env['DB_HOST']}:{env['DB_PORT']}/{env['DB_NAME']}"
    return create_engine(PG_URI,
                         echo=False,
                         echo_pool='debug',
                         pool_size=5,
                         pool_timeout=5,
                         pool_pre_ping=True,
                         isolation_level='AUTOCOMMIT',
                         connect_args={
                             "connect_timeout": 5,
                             "options": f"-c statement-timeout={5 * 1000}",
                         },
    )


def test_gc(engine):
    conn = engine.connect()
    db = Session(conn)
    print(db.execute(text("SELECT 1 + 1")).fetchone())

def main():
    engine = get_engine(os.environ)
    test_gc(engine)
    print(engine.pool.status())
    import gc
    gc.collect()
    print(engine.pool.status())

OUTPUT
You can see the first call to status() shows the connection is still checked out.
2024-12-30 22:45:03,314 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool Created new connection <psycopg.Connection [IDLE] (host=so_testing_db database=so_testing) at 0x7fbafff12410>
2024-12-30 22:45:03,318 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool Connection <psycopg.Connection [IDLE] (host=so_testing_db database=so_testing) at 0x7fbafff12410> checked out from pool
2024-12-30 22:45:03,318 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool Connection <psycopg.Connection [IDLE] (host=so_testing_db database=so_testing) at 0x7fbafff12410> is fresh, skipping pre-ping
(2,)
Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
2024-12-30 22:45:03,333 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool Connection <psycopg.Connection [IDLE] (host=so_testing_db database=so_testing) at 0x7fbafff12410> being returned to pool
2024-12-30 22:45:03,333 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool Connection <psycopg.Connection [IDLE] (host=so_testing_db database=so_testing) at 0x7fbafff12410> rollback-on-return
Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0


When a Session is created a connection resource is requested from the Engine.  The connection remains open until the transaction completes, which can happen when a rollback or commit is called. In the case of autocommit, the commit occurs immediately after a statement is processed.  At this point the transaction ends and the underlying connection resource is returned back to the connection pool.
Based on my understanding of how SQLAlchemy manages its connection pools, it seems safe to not explicitly close sessions. GC would clean up any Session objects that were no longer referenced. But there's no advantage to keeping sessions alive, that I'm aware of, and best practice is normally to close resources when they're no longer needed.
